# AVD unable to lauch

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I run the project the .apk file get uploaded and installed successfully on the device but AVD unbale to launch. Please help me to solve this issue.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.bottleworks.dailymoney.core"> 
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest.xml.

Comment: Can you give more explanation please.Because "but AVD unable to launch " means, whether it showing any warning or error message.

Comment: @ReddyPrasad There are no error only few warning

Answer (score 0):

If it gives message "unable to upload file **timeout**" or something similar to that then close the emulator and run the app again

Otherwise post the **logcat** here to get better kind of solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the list of existing AVDs located in this folder

C:\Users\youruser\.android\avd

or test it this way :

1- right click in your app

2- run as => run configurations

3- Target Tab => manager

and post your error if you have any

Answer (score 0):

you need to add application tag also in manifest.xml file.

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplahScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


 </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OtherActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```